# Streaming data from Neo4j to Gephi - "Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xfc"

Tags: neo4j, gephi, neo4j-apoc

I have recently started working with Neo4j and I am interested in visualizing my graph in Gephi. To do that, I am trying to use the apoc procedure

```
CALL apoc.gephi.add(null,'workspace1', paths) yield nodes, relationships, time
RETURN nodes, relationships, time
```

Some of my nodes have accented characters such as ö or å and that seems to be giving me trouble because I obtain the following error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure 'apoc.gephi.add': Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xfc at [Source: apoc.export.util.CountingInputStream@599da1f9; line: 19, column: 125]
```

On Gephi I obtain some of the nodes but not all of them or the relationships. This doesn't happen when I work with a database without special characters (like the movie database).

I am using

- Windows 7
- Neo4j Desktop 1.1.9
- Neo4j 3.4.1
- APOC 3.4.0.1
- Gephi 0.9.2
- Spanish locale

This is a similar problem to [this one](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/740) but it remains unsolved. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is an unresolved [bug](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/740#issuecomment-381627206) in the windows version of Gephi. So you will need to do one of the following

- Run Gephi on linux inside a VM or Docker container
- Remove the special characters from the data (I believe this is triggered by non ASCII characters like `'ä', 'Ä', 'ü', 'Ü', 'ö', 'Ö', 'ß'`)
- Update Gephi to a newer version (if one is out)

Comment: Thank you, that is what I feared. Given the nature of the data, I cannot get rid of the non ASCII characters and it looks like 0.9.2 is the latest version of Gephi. Probably the best solution would be to run it on Linux as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible workaround while the issue is solved. If the graph from Neo4j is exported as a graphml and then imported on Gephi, there are no problem with the non ASCII characters.